# My app frequently dies

Tags: android

I don't know if this is the right way to ask for help, but I recently uploaded a app to the google play store. Here a link to [my app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.krissini.server)

a submitted error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
    at de.krissini.server.GamePanel.onDraw(GamePanel.java:230)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15249)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.draw(SurfaceView.java:340)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14185)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14207)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14145)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14207)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14145)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14207)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14145)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14207)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:273)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:279)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:318)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2560)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2382)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2012)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5990)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

omg now it needs more text blablabla sorry, don't read this please

Comment: The developer console will notify you of a crash and provide you some logs that could help identify the problem. Try getting those and post them here. Also if you're not already using one, there are many issue tracking solution that are high recommended for applications on the market, one of them is crashlytics by fabric.

Comment: The concurrentModificationException usually happens when you are modifying a list while another thread is iterating over it. I can see in your code your are modifying smoke and missiles, are these being used anywhere else while ur modifying them? Also considered editing your question, instead of adding new comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you:
It creates shallow copy of your collections and iterates over copies instead the original ones.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (canvas != null && getHolder().getSurface().isValid()) {
        bg.draw(canvas);
        player.draw(canvas);
        if (player.getPlaying()) {
            List<Smokepuff> copySmoke = new ArrayList<Smokepuff>(smoke);
            List<Missle> copyMissles = new ArrayList<Missle>(missles);
            for (Smokepuff sp : copySmoke) {
                sp.draw(canvas);
            }
            for (Missle m : copyMissles) {
                m.draw(canvas);
            }
            drawScore(canvas);
        }
        postInvalidate();
    }
}
```

**However** you should think why it crashes here in the first place.

`ConcurrentModificationException` happens when you try to modify the collection while iterating over it. Do you use that collection in multiple threads? If yes, you should consider some synchronization. Especially when it comes to add and remove operations.

The `onDraw()` will be called very often, so making copies of collections in it's every call **might not be a great idea** due to performance issues. It will help you, but I still recommend to check all of the places where you use those collections in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (canvas != null && getHolder().getSurface().isValid()) {
        bg.draw(canvas);
        player.draw(canvas);
        if (player.getPlaying()) {
            for (Smokepuff sp : smoke) {
                sp.draw(canvas);
            }
            for (Missle m : missles) {
                m.draw(canvas);
            }
            drawScore(canvas);
        }
        postInvalidate();
    }
}
```